# Jersey POJOMappingFeature exclude null properties from JSON

Tags: json, jersey-2.0

I have using Jersey Rest APIs and POJOMappingFeature to convert Objects to JSON.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.rest.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>**
```

Where my JSON object is like below:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User{
// Other properties goes here
}
```

While returning this from my Jersey REST API, null values are not ignored.That means JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL is not applied.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

@JsonInclude is an annotation from [Jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html). POJOMappingFeature is a Jersey feature and therefore will not take your Jackson annotations into account when serializing your POJOs.

You could use [Jackson JAX-RS Providers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers). Then your REST API will be able to use Jackson to serialize the objects returned by your endpoints into JSON.